# Adjust Background Image as per screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way available to adjust background images for all screen sizes instead of doing that programmaticaly?

Comment: Can you at least show us some codes / how you implement the background image? do you use an `UIImageView` in Storyboard to display the background image?

Comment: are u using autolayout ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set `UIImageview` contentmode to `AspectFill/AspectFit` in Xib/storyboard other wise you do programatically like this

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`  //fill the frame, possibly cutting off parts of your image

or

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`  //show the entire image, possibly leaving areas of the frame open

Comment: how it possible? did you read apple ui guidelines because every screen size different based on resolution like @2x,@3x. it thought it not work smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout in storyboard file
 and set property for image is AspectFill of AspectFit.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this is good approach. if any knows pls share.

this is works only iOS7 above.

```
#define isPhone568 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
#define isPhone667 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)
#define iPhone568ImageNamed(image) (isPhone568 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h.%@", [image stringByDeletingPathExtension], [image pathExtension]] : isPhone667 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-667h.%@", [image stringByDeletingPathExtension], [image pathExtension]]:image)
```

iPhone 5 screen size - 568 
iPhone 6 screen size - 667
iPhone 6+ use- image@3x
others use - image@2x